Has any mass protest in the USA after 1945 successfully pressured the government to change its decision based on the protesters' demands?
As far as I recall, several mass protests took place in the USA against the Vietnam War, and the government quelled them using violent means, such as the Kent State shooting, etc.
Has any mass protest in the USA after 1945 successfully pressured the government to change its decision based on the protesters' demands?

This question already has a close vote for being opinion-based.  I concur, but I think this question is fine if the OP simply removes the "if not, why?" from the end of the text.

I agree, there's a strong opinion-based element here. For instance, the question's example of protests that did not change a government's posture were protests against the Vietnam War. But you can find people arguing exactly the opposite: the USA withdrew from the war in 1973; after having expanded the war into Cambodia, Nixon later withdrew American troops altogether. Some scholars credibly argue that social pressure due to nearly two decades of massive protests had something to do with that. Whether or not they are correct, people argue both sides based on different interpretations.

It's fundamentally very difficult, when a country's government changes its policy, to know what factors caused it and in what degree—and even politicians occasional claims before or after the fact are suspect—so speculation tends to fill in the gaps, with government supporters usually saying that the situation changed and protesters saying that nothing would have changed if they had not spoken up.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Have_a_Dream

It's usually difficult to prove cause and effect for protests unless there's something of the magnitude of the gov't fleeing in a helicopter etc. Concomitant with protests there are opinion polls etc., which may sway a government in a democracy more, in view of elections. Sometimes a noisy minority can protest all day long without a real chance of affecting elections.

Nixon would in fact insist he was not pressured by protests in re Vietnam. He had counter-protests going etc.

FWTW https://www.ucf.edu/news/7-influential-protests-in-american-history/

As IVF points out, it is almost impossible to see a direct variation between one protest and a policy change. But protests make issues visible and put them in the political discourse, which can lead to changes. The civil rights movement staged many protests; you probably cannot link any specific change to one of them but you cannot deny their influence, either.

By "the government", do you refer solely to "the federal government of the USA" or do state and local governments count as well?  Legislative actions only, or also administrative policy changes?

Protest is generally a tool to communicate to the public, who then direct the politicians to legislate appropriately or risk being voted out of office. Direct effect on  political decisions is much less common.

Not sure if this is a cause for closing, but the OP’s characterization of the Vietnam war protests being “quelled…using violent means” is a gross misrepresentation of what actually happened. The Kent State shooting is so famous precisely because it was such an anomaly.  And it did not by any means “quell” protests. Just one example from a year later here

I'm in NZ. Citing the Kent State shooting as " ... the government quelled them by violent means ..." suggests a strongly biased agenda or a failure to do more than skim through the headlines. The KSS were exceedingly anomalous. The outcome was never in any way intended in advance by any party - not government in any form, not the ROTC members and not the "crowd". While they cannot be blamed for the beyond tragic outcome the "crowd" very much share a significant part of the responsibility for the behaivour which put vastly undertrained young men, armed when they should not have been in a ...

... situation where it got too much for one of them and, as too often happens in such situations, it "snowballed" from there. There are any number of examples of intentional US law enforcement intentional brutality and overreach - but the  Kent State tragedy is in a quite different class. || Choose a better example, if you must. You say "Lent State etc" - what were your other best few examples?

"several mass protests took place in the USA against the Vietnam War" More like thousands of them.


Has any mass protest in the USA after 1945 successfully pressured the government to change its decision based on the protesters' demands?

One single mass protest? Probably not. It takes a concerted, long-term effort to change behaviors (and laws).
That said, the civil rights movement from the late 1940s to the late 1960s certainly qualifies. The protests ranged from very small scale (e.g., Rosa Parks) to very large scale (e.g., the August 1963 March on Washington). The cumulative effects of these protests included executive orders, Supreme Court decisions, and federal legislative acts.

In the 1970s and 80s there were multiple laws and regulations that discriminated against people from the lgbtq community.
There was a protest movement, including for example, the April 25 1993 march on Washington.
Attitudes towards homosexuality have changed. The government (or "governments", since this time spans multiple administrations) has changed many of the discriminatory policies (though some remain) in particular "Don't ask don't tell" is no longer a policy in the military.
The widespread (and almost entirely non-violent) protests affected US culture. It seems unreasonable to suggest that the raft of discriminatory laws and regulations would have been repealed if there hadn't been such protests. But of course, it is impossible to tie any particular legislative or executive act directly to a protest.

There was also a protest against the FDA paper pushers for needlessly delaying HIV therapies. Fauci famously met with the protesters back in the day and the FDA removed some of the BS so that people could actually be saved from AIDS.

Fauci was and is a fabulous man.  It is a shame that he was a member of the administration he was a member of the administration did not recognize his brilliance as a scientist nor his talents as a human being.

@user1928764 We're getting a bit off track here, but Fauci was not a member of the Trump administration. In particular, he was not a political appointee. He was instead a career public servant who had worked under multiple administrations for over fifty years. Note very well: Career federal civil servants who are not Presidential appointees swear an oath to a lil' old piece of paper (the US Constitution) rather than to the President.

While the change in attitude towards homosexuality in the armed forces is certainly not entirely irrelevant, the much bigger win for the US LGBT community at large is probably the right to same-sex marriage.

Yes, equal marriage wasn't part of the debate in 1993. The protestors mentioned "family diversity", and wanted equality in "custody, adoption and foster care", but there is nothing about marriage.

Why slip partisan commentary in the answer?

Since I'm not a partisan of US politics..... I think you may be projecting.

The George Floyd protests in Colorado were the primary reason that the Colorado General Assembly (the state legislature) adopted major reforms designed to discourage excessive uses of force by police, including creating a state version of federal civil rights claims but without qualified immunity, banning choke holds in most circumstances, and several other major reforms.
A long series of protests called the Civil Rights movement lead to the ban on racial discrimination in employment, housing, public accommodations, and education, to the end of sex discrimination in employment (laws that were later applied to also end discrimination based upon sexual orientation and transgender status), and to prosecution of civil rights related murders the when taken seriously basically ended lynching in the United States. These outcomes were intimately related to the many mass protests and "street politics" urging that they be adopted. The post-WWII Civil Rights movement was also the main driver of the adoption of the 23rd Amendment (DC voting in Presidential elections), and the 24th Amendment (prohibiting poll taxes).
Protests are the reason that women can now wear pants in public, even in formal settings like courts.
While they were lower key, protests organized by Mothers Against Drunk Driving had a major impact on laws regulating youth drinking and regulation drunk driving offenses and enforcement.
Do strikes count as protests? Because labor actions by unions were a major cause of stronger wage and hour laws, of stronger protections for unions, of the workplace safety regime that is embodied in OSHA and MSHA, in adopting Labor Day as a national holiday, in making weekends the norm, and a variety of other protections for workers.
Protests were one component of many in a multi-faceted campaign to secure stronger environmental laws. Initially, it rode piggy-back on the civil rights movement as part of the environmental justice movement.
The Vietnam War protests mentioned in the question were pivotal in securing the reduction of the voting age from age twenty-one to age eighteen in the 26th Amendment.
The ends secured by protests aren't just liberal ones. The long history of protests by the anti-abortion movement were pivotal in causing conservative Presidents to appoint anti-abortion judges to the U.S. Supreme Court who ultimately reversed Roe v. Wade in the recent Dobbs decision, and causing state legislators to adopt anti-abortion legislation.
Protests are probably more effective at the local government level although they rarely make headlines in the same way, and are much less partisan in character.
Real estate developers routinely have their development plans thwarted by grass roots NIMBY protests appealing to municipal governments all over the country.
Local school board decisions to close schools are frequently reversed or significantly delayed in the face of protests seeking to keep the schools on the chopping block open.
Certainly, there are countries where protests are much more central in securing policy changes than the U.S. France comes to mind on a whole host of issues. Protests were pivotal in ending the communist regime in East Germany. But that doesn't mean that the U.S. doesn't have them, or that they don't work some of the time.

Funny how when you ask "has any" you only need to find one example to say yes.
In the buildup to tractorcade, some farmers were arrested in Austin and were charged with various crimes. A siege like protest at the jail by the rest of the gathering of farmers in Austin was sufficient to convince the DA to back down.

Attorney General John Hill arrived on scene from Austin and negotiated a settlement: All charges dropped, no fines imposed, and all farmers free to go.

Funny way of saying the attorney general gave up.
As for tractorcade itself on Washington, DC; it's somewhat disputed. It did not accomplish its objectives but appears to have of itself change the situation for the better.

Almost 42 years beyond Tractorcade, Kimbrell poses and answers a simple question: “Did we do any good? Maybe the young guys don’t know it, but the safeguards in place now are partly a result of farmers sounding the alarm bell in the 1970s. Tractorcade led right to the United Farmer & Rancher Congress in St. Louis, and that led to legislative changes. All these things tie together and can be traced from back then to today.”

https://www.agweb.com/news/policy/politics/tractorcade-how-epic-convoy-and-legendary-farmer-army-shook-washington-d-c
